# Short sci-fi story about a musician's last concert

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This short story relates to a future musician's last concert. It is told from the perspective of one of the fans of the musician. In the story he relates the wonder of listening to the musician's music and how sad it is that this is the last live concert he will ever see.

The story concludes with all the audience being transfixed by the music and living their lives slowly, forever listening to the last concert.

I'm sure it was part of an anthology.

Comment: So, at the end, is the end that time "stops" for the concert attendees because they're so engrossed by the music? Or is it implied that somehow the concert lasts forever?